# Azure EventGrid Webhook timeout

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-eventgrid

Came to know from the documentation that timeout for webhook is 60 secs. If that's the case then are we expecting developers to do asynchronous operations? I mean what if the work that I want to do as part of the webhook takes more than 60 secs? But if we make that operation asynchronous and the work I want do as part of the webhook fails then how do we recover from that situation because we already responded event grid 200 OK. In that case - would we lose the event?

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario like yours such as the event handler processing over 60 seconds, the following can be implemented, based on the retrying and dead-lettering technique:

- use the primary event subscription with a retry policy and
  dead-lettering. This subscriber (function) with a binding to the storage table will handle a state of the long running (max 24 hrs) event processing and also forwarding the first event message to to the storage queue for triggering a long running process. The response from this primary subscriber will depend from the state of the StorageQueueTrigger function.
- every new retry event message will check the state of the long running process and based on that, the response code (for instance OK(200) or Service.Unavailable(503)) is sent back to the Event Grid.

In the above scenario, the retry mechanism represents a "watchdog timer" for watching a long running event message processing. The second function such as QueueTrigger function is yielding a process between the Event Grid and long running process.

In summary, your scenario will require the following:

- EventSubscriber with retry policy and dead-lettering for Webhook (EventGridTrigger or HttpTrigger function)
- EventGridTrigger or HttpTrigger function
- Storage Table
- QueueTrigger Function

If anything unusually happen during the watchdog timer, the dead-lettering is sent to your container storage with a deadLetterReason.

Note, that in the case if your long running process is over 5/10 minutes, the StorageQueue trigger needs to be considered in the App Service plan or using your custom worker processor.

**Update:**

The following screen snippet shows the above solution for "long running subscriber" with a Watchdog timer:

[image: WithWatchdogTimer]

also it can be used directly a StorageQueue Event Handler to yield the long running process from the EventGrid, but in this case, the function has a more responsibilities such as retrying, notification, dead-lettering, etc., see the following picture:

[image]